# Spring Batch, Update statement in a writer? Throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

To be as concise as possible,

I have a master step that splits the execution off into parallel slaves.

These slaves each have their own context, which stores the ID of the thread they're executed on, `runNumber`. They are reader, processor, writer steps. The write of this slave is what I'm concerned with. I have a `CompositeItemWriter` that has a writer that I want to do an SQL update statement that updates the thread's success in a db. This writer is below:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<TraceDataDto> controlSuccessWriter(
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['runNumber']}") int runNumber,
        @Qualifier("veDataSource") DataSource veDataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<TraceDataDto> mysqlWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();

    mysqlWriter.setDataSource(veDataSource);

    String sql = "UPDATE control SET status=1 WHERE run_number=" + runNumber;

    mysqlWriter.setSql(sql);

    return mysqlWriter;
}
```

Now, I'm having trouble with this as it spits an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Using SQL statement with '?'
>   placeholders requires an ItemPreparedStatementSetter

Now I know there's a path I can go down to create a custom class that implements `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` but I'm concerned that's going to create unnecessary overhead by mapping single values to objects.

Is there an easy way I can just execute this update statement as part of the slave step?

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemWriter` implementations provided by Spring Batch are expected to persist items.  That's not what you're trying to do so I'd recommend creating an `ItemWriter` (or even better a listener) that just uses `JdbcTemplate` to execute the query you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

...

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

...

JdbcBatchItemWriter<TraceDataDto> updateItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<TraceDataDto>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("UPDATE control SET status=1 WHERE run_number=" + runNumber + 
            " AND LENGTH(control.<someNonNullCharColumn>) >= LENGTH(:<TraceDataDto::someStringField>")
        .dataSource(dataSource).build();
// dummy list to trigger at least one statement
List<TraceDataDto> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();
// here at least TraceDataDto::someStringField should be set to ""
TraceDataDto dummyTdd = new TraceDataDto("a", "b", 2, 3.14, ...);
dummyList.add(dummyTdd);
// to avoid exception: 
// java.lang.NullPointerException: null
// at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:190)
deleteItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
try {
    updateItemWriter.write(dummyList);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no action
}
```

The trick here is to use a SQL statement containing `:fieldName` placeholders, so that you can use a `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` instead of an `ItemPreparedStatementSetter`.
This is just an example, you want to use the `:fieldName` in a WHERE clause selecting all the rows, which is ANDed with your actual clause.